# How to add date time using Angular 720kb.datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I need one help .I need to add date with time using Angular.js. I used `720kb.datepicker` but it able to add only date.I am adding my code below.

```
<div class="datepicker" date-format="dd-MM-y" button-prev='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>' button-next='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>'> 
 <input type="text" name="birthdate" class="form-control" id="date" ng-model="date" placeholder="Add Expiry Date" ng-change="clearField('date');" />
</div>
```

Here i am getting only date but i need date and time both after selecting date.Please help me.

Comment: Well, right away I see that your `date-format` only has room for the date, not the time.  Try changing that first?

Comment: what should it be.

Comment: That depends on the format you want to get back.  I would think `date-format="dd-MM-y h:mm"` should be a good start though.  There's a comprehensive list [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Comment: i did like this `date-format=dd-MM-y h:mm:ss` but it is taking only one time.

Comment: @satya Can you describe what do you mean by taking only one time.. I.e. what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: suppose i selected one date ,its coming like this `14-03-2016 12:00:00`.but before 15 min time was also same.

Answer (score 0):

As described on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker) of the project:

> Angular datepicker is an angularjs directive that generates a
>   **datepicker calendar** on your input element.

In other words, it is a datepicker, nothing more, nothing less. If you would like to be able to pick a time as well, you'll either need to build your own timepicker, extend this library or look for one on the internet.

You can find some similar projects [here](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-datetime-picker). I would also recommend looking into Angular UI Bootstrap, which contains both a [datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) and a [timepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker).

Answer (score 0):

***you can use default angular.js function for getting date***

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
<input type="date" ng-model="date" value="{{ date | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd' }}" />
<br />
Selected Date : {{ date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
</div>
```